# Standard Form Ellipse Through Three Points and Parallel to X and Y Axes

Tags: geometry

I want the general form $\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1$ for an ellipse with a specified eccentricity $e$ that passes through three (non-collinear) points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ and is parallel to the X and Y axes (i.e. major axis of ellipse parallel to the X axis and minor axis parallel to the Y axis).

I found this gem on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ellipse):
$$
\frac{({\color{red}x} - x_1)({\color{red}x} - x_2) + {\color{blue}q}\;({\color{red}y} - y_1)({\color{red}y} - y_2)}
             {({\color{red}y} - y_1)({\color{red}x} - x_2) - ({\color{red}y} - y_2)({\color{red}x} - x_1)} =
        \frac{(x_3 - x_1)(x_3 - x_2) + {\color{blue}q}\;(y_3 - y_1)(y_3 - y_2)}
             {(y_3 - y_1)(x_3 - x_2) - (y_3 - y_2)(x_3 - x_1)}\ .
$$
where ${\color{blue}q} = \frac{a^2}{b^2} = \frac{1}{1 - e^2}$, which I think is supposed to work, but a) converting this equation to standard form is a bear (and maybe isn't doable?), and b) seems to introduce $xy$ terms which leads me to believe the ellipse will be tilted with respect to the X and Y axes.

Is this the right equation to be working with?  If so, is there a standard form of the equation?  Is there a different/better way to accomplish the task?

P.S. Having the standard form is pretty important: I'm going to use this with a graphics app where knowing $x_0, y_0, a,$ and $b$ is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, the equation can be re-arranged in a compact form:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
  (1-e^2)x^2+y^2 & x & y & 1 \\
  (1-e^2)x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
  (1-e^2)x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
  (1-e^2)x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

where $e\ne 1$ and comparing with the general form

$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$

Now,

\begin{align}
  A &= (1-e^2) C \\ \\
  B &= 0 \\ \\
  C &=
  \begin{vmatrix}
    x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
    x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
    x_3 & y_3 & 1
  \end{vmatrix} \\ \\
  D &= -
  \begin{vmatrix}
    (1-e^2)x_1^2+y_1^2 & y_1 & 1 \\
    (1-e^2)x_2^2+y_2^2 & y_2 & 1 \\
    (1-e^2)x_3^2+y_3^2 & y_3 & 1
  \end{vmatrix} \\ \\
  E &=
  \begin{vmatrix}
    (1-e^2)x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
    (1-e^2)x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
    (1-e^2)x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & 1
  \end{vmatrix} \\ \\
  F &= -
  \begin{vmatrix}
    (1-e^2)x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 \\
    (1-e^2)x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 \\
    (1-e^2)x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3
  \end{vmatrix} \\
\end{align}

Re-arrange the equation as

$$A
\left( x+\frac{D}{2A} \right)^2+
C
\left( y+\frac{E}{2C} \right)^2=
\frac{D^2}{4A}+\frac{E^2}{4C}-F$$

implying the centre is

$$\left( -\frac{D}{2A}, -\frac{E}{2C} \right)$$

and the semi-axes

$$
(a,b)=
\left(
  \sqrt{\frac{D^2}{4A^2}+\frac{E^2}{4AC}-\frac{F}{A}},
  \sqrt{\frac{D^2}{4AC}+\frac{E^2}{4C^2}-\frac{F}{C}}
\right)$$

for $0 \le e<1$.

Comment: Is there an extra row in the definition for F?

Comment: corrected with thanks

Comment: Thank *you*.  A useful and informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably not try to work with the standard form equation directly but use the general form instead. However, I'd use the standard form equation to generate a 'simpler' general form equation.

First, since you have a specified eccentricity $e$, and $a > b$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
e &= \sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2}} \\
\\
a^2 e^2 &= a^2 - b^2 \\
\\
b^2 &= a^2 (1-e^2)
\end{align}
$$

Then, substituting this into the standard form equation gives

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{a^2 (1-e^2)} &= 1 \\
\\
(1-e^2)(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 &= a^2 (1-e^2)
\end{align}
$$

From this it's clear that in expanded form, the coefficient of $x^2$ will be $(1-e^2)$ and the coefficient of $y^2$ will be $1$. Thus the general form equation will be

$$(1-e^2) \, x^2 + y^2 + D \, x + E \, y + F = 0$$

so using the three points you're given will yield a linear three-variable system which can be solved for $D, E \, $ and $\, F$. Then convert to standard form.

Comment: Thanks @AJ.  An informative and useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using *Mathematica* to do some symbol-crunching on the three-point formula, we get
(switching subscripts to $0$, $1$, $2$ to make modular arithmetic nicer):

$$\frac{(x - h)^2}{a^2m} + 
  \frac{(y - k)^2}{b^2m} = 1 \tag{$\star$}$$

where

$$\begin{align}
m & := \phantom{-}\frac {1} {4a^4 b^4 t^2}\prod_ {i = 0}^2\left (\; 
    a^2 (y_ {i + 1} - y_ {i - 1})^2 + b^2 (x_ {i + 1} - x_ {i - 1})^2 \;\right) \tag{1.m}\\[6pt]
h &:= \phantom{-}\frac {1} {2b^2t}\left (\; 
    a^2 (y_ 1 - y_ 2) (y_ 2 - y_ 0) (y_ 0 - y_ 1) + 
     b^2\sum_ {i = 0}^2 y_i (x^2 _ {i + 1} - 
         x^2 _ {i - 1})\; \right) \tag{1.h}\\[6 pt]
k &:= -\frac {1} {2a^2t}\left (\; 
    b^2 (x_ 1 - x_ 2) (x_ 2 - x_ 0) (x_ 0 - x_ 1) + 
     a^2\sum_ {i = 0}^2 x_i (y^2 _ {i + 1} - 
         y^2 _ {i - 1})\; \right) \tag{1.k}\\[6pt]
t &:= \phantom{-}\sum_{i=0}^2 \left( x_{i-1} y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_{i-1} \right)  \tag{1.t}
\end{align}$$
(with subscript arithmetic performed *modulo* $3$) and I've used $a$ and $b$ for notational balance and to add orientational flexibility. For an ellipse of eccentricity $e$ with a horizontal major axis, substitute $a\to 1$ and $b\to 1-e^2$; for a vertical major axis, substitute $a\to 1-e^2$ and $b\to 1$. $\square$

As a sanity check, one could/should verify that, when $a=b=1$ (that is, $e=0$), the above gives the equation of the [circumcircle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html) of the three given points. I'm out of time right now, so for the moment I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks, @Blue.  An interesting answer, perhaps a bit less direct than the others, but still useful.